# GTKSharp, Pango, set font size quirkiness

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#, pango

I'm using GTK Sharp to work on some GUI for my app.

Take a look at this chunk of code:

```
Pango.FontDescription fontdesc = new Pango.FontDescription();
fontdesc.Family = "Sans";
//fontdesc.Size = 12;
fontdesc.Weight = Pango.Weight.Semibold;
SyncInfo.ModifyFont(fontdesc);
Gdk.Color fontcolor = new Gdk.Color(255,255,255);
SyncInfo.ModifyFg(StateType.Normal, fontcolor);
```

Notice fontdesc.Size is commented out. Because only when I comment it out, will I see the  label with text. If I set any value to it, the label will not appear.

Also, I did a Console.WriteLine, and the default Size is 0. So I tried frontdesc.Size = 0, and it still disappears, any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=P%3aPango.FontDescription.Size) out.  You need to set it to 12 * Scale.PangoScale.  I had a similar problem with the C APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a C# version of the other PangoScale answer:

```
Pango.FontDescription fontdesc = new Pango.FontDescription();
fontdesc.Size = Convert.ToInt32(12 * Pango.Scale.PangoScale);
....
```

Notes:  FontDescription.Size is a *int* and PangoScale is type *double* so a type cast or other double to int conversion is needed.
*Scale* is likely ambiguous in the referenced name spaces, so the full reference Pango.Scale is probably best used.